# How to tell which modules have been imported in some source code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to inspect source code (or compiled code object) and tell what modules are being imported in Python 3.3?

For instance, in:

```
import foo

def func():
    from bar import *
    return 42
```

I'd like to be able to tell that modules foo and bar were being imported.  I'm hoping to avoid regex or pattern matching.

Comment: Did you mean to shadow the imported foo with your function def?

Comment: Er, no.  Just my love affair with foo.  Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to analyse the code.

```
import ast

class ImportNodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Import(self, node):
        print(ast.dump(node))
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        print(ast.dump(node))
        self.generic_visit(node)


with open(sourcefilename) as sf:
    tree = ast.parse(sf.read(), sourcefilename)
    ImportNodeVisitor().visit(tree)
```

produces

```
Import(names=[alias(name='foo', asname=None)])
ImportFrom(module='bar', names=[alias(name='*', asname=None)], level=0)
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks Martijn.  Hadn't played around with visiting AST nodes.